# Regular Expression with phrases alternatives

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get list of phrases on string with `regex`, i need to get this:

```
- "teste"
on:
CREATE TABLE teste 
or
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teste
```

I'm trying this:

```
 CREATE (TABLE|TABLE IF NOT EXISTS) ([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Any sugestions ?

Thanks !

-- update

I need get only "teste"... how I can get in this expression that if I need use parenthesis on "table group" ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with “it doesn't it make sense”? If your regex doesn't work, it might also help to tell us which tool or programming language you're using.

Comment: Hey, there! I'm not asking for you to change it back, it is OK as it is, but I'm curious, why did you change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Balancin, do you want find this in java?

```
String regexToFind = ".*[tT][eE][sS][tT][eE].*";
String inputOk = "CREATE TABLE teste ";
String inputNotOk = "CREATE TABLE notok ";
System.out.println(inputOk.matches(regexToFind));
System.out.println(inputNotOk.matches(regexToFind));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is not working as expected because the order of the operands for the alternation operator (`|`) matter to some engines. What happens is: as soon as it matches `TABLE`, the engine will **not** continue and try to match the second operand (`TABLE IF NOT...`) because it will consider the group matched and go on, thus the `IF NOT...` part would be matched by the `([a-zA-Z]+)` expression.

---

The cleanest/safest **solution** would be to use the `?` operator to make the expression optional:

```
CREATE TABLE( IF NOT EXISTS)? ([a-zA-Z]+)
```

[Demo here.](http://regexr.com?37rki)

Or change the order of the operands in the alternation operator `|` (it matters to some engines):

```
CREATE (TABLE IF NOT EXISTS|TABLE) ([a-zA-Z]+)
```

[Demo for this second one](http://regexr.com?37rkf).

---

Also note that the word `"teste"` on your example would be matched by the **group number two**. If you want it to be matched by the first group, use non-capturing groups (through `?:`) as in:

```
CREATE TABLE(?: IF NOT EXISTS)? ([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Comment: In this case i can't match the (...table...) so... i need match only "teste", how I do it ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to

- accept *all* whitespace characters, not just spaces (`\s+`)
- find *all* occurrences (`/g` or CASE_INSENSITIVE in Java)
- search case insensitive (`/i`)

`/create\s+table\s+(if not exists)?\s+([a-zA-Z]+)/gi`

When this regular expression matches, the table name can be found in the second match group. Depending on your environment, you can access it with `\2`, `$2`, `group(2)`, etc.

In Java, you have to escape backslashes which makes it a bit harder to read. Here's a Java example:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("create\\s+table\\s+(if\\s+not\\s+exists\\s+)?([a-zA-Z]+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("bla bla CREATE TABLE foo; bla bla create table if not exists bar;");
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("table: " + matcher.group(2));
  }
}
```

will print:

```
table: foo
table: bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you ignore case, too.  Table names can contain numbers.

```
(CREATE TABLE|CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS)\s+(\w+)
```